# building a tree structure, getting strange duplication issue

Tags: ruby, tree, duplicates

I'm trying to build a web scraper that allows me to define how to scrape a page via a DSL. First a tree (not a binary tree) is compiled then that tree is used to scrape the page.

The problem is I'm getting some weird duplication issue, despite the block of code that adds the fields being called three times, somehow the field's are being added to every node (of which there're are 5). I can't work out how or why this is happening, so I thought I'd ask stack.

The important code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Thermatix/0494384fd82cc90d061b140d8d6e7784), I set the terminal output to .json so it would be easier to read.

EDIT:

I've been looking at the `object_ids` of the hashes, the container hashes (`@data`) within the `Node` objects have different ids but the `fields` hashes inside the container hashes all seem to share the same ID's, so updating one updates the others.

I'm not sure why that's happening as I'm duping (now cloning) the init hash I pass into the initial tree node, why is the hash still referencing the same hash object.

Comment: Yeah, hi, person that voted to close this? according to the scope of the help center, this is very much on topic. It's a 'a specific programming problem' even if where the problem is isn't exact (becuase I don't know exactly where the issue is) and it's definitely on topic  because there IS output included and I've even narrowed it down it down. If you can't be bothered to read the OP properly, fine just don't vote to close as a result, makes you look stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to solve the issue I had to change the mechanism that sets the items in the `@data` container so it now essentially creates a new copy of the has every time it adds to so now it looks like this:

```
def set_info(type,name,xpath,meta)
  #see, I have to grab the current hash then merge the new data into it and then overwrite the old hash with the new one :(
  @tree[@tree_pointer].data[type] = @tree[@tree_pointer].data[type].merge({name => {
    xpath: join_xpath(xpath),
    meta: meta
  }})
end
```

certainly not ideal but it was the only way to ensure that ruby stops copying a reference and actually creates a separate hash object, the duplication issue is now gone.

Still, if someone has a better way to do this I'm all ears.